# Why is this std::vector being cleared when program enters main function?

Tags: c++, vector, static, initialization

The problem I'm having is that I am pushing an element into a vector at initialisation when all the static variables are initialised, and then when it enters the main function the vector resets to 0, as if it has cleared. In my case the vector was in a different CPP, but this also shows the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct List
{
    static std::vector<int> listVector;
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo() 
    {
        std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 0
        List::listVector.push_back(1);
        std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 1
    }
};
Foo fooObj;

std::vector<int> List::listVector;

int main()
{
    std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 0
    List::listVector.push_back(2);
    std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 1
}
```

The first element I added to the vector has been lost. I know one has to be careful with initialisation order of static global variables, but I can't understand why the vector is being cleared. I'm tempted to think that when the Foo constructor runs it adds an element to the vector, but the vector hasn't been created yet, because it's written on the line after the Foo object is created. However, if this is the case, just what vector am I adding into when I do so in the constructor and it prints out a size of 1?

I'm kind of confused.

Comment: Don't have time to find standard links, but initialization order of `fooObj` and `listVector` is suspect. Replace the vector with your own class and add printing or something to the constructor etc.

Comment: To be clear, this should be distinct from the Static Initialization Order Fiasco because it's the same translation unit.

Comment: I believe they're being initialised correctly, using my own vector class, it doesn't call the destructor until after the Foo constructor. This makes sense as the initialisation order should be as it appears in the code. What I'm really confused about is what vector was being added to when I pushed back an element and the size went to 1, only to go back to 0 when it enters main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm tempted to think that when the Foo constructor runs it adds an element to the vector, but the vector hasn't been created yet, because it's written on the line after the Foo object is created.

Yes, that's exactly right. The `fooObj` constructor just accesses the memory where the vector *will* be constructed, but it hasn't been constructed there yet. (So the program has undefined behaviour, and must be fixed)

> However, if this is the case, just what vector am I adding into when I do so in the constructor and it prints out a size of 1?

The compiler simply interprets the memory as being a valid vector, because it has no way to know otherwise. That just happens to work, because the memory that the global will be constructed in is initially zero, because the execution environment ensures that all static objects' memory is initially zero, which happens to be the same as the default-constructed state (for your implementation's definition of `std::vector`). The program has no way to know that the memory location containing all-zeros is not a valid vector yet.

Later the constructor for the vector runs and *re-initializes* the memory, to the default-constructed state.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44acad87ae7b8c7f) is an example showing what your program does: interpreting raw memory containing all zeros as a vector, and adding elements to that phantom vector (which doesn't really exist), then actually constructing a vector in that memory. Anything added to the phantom vector is lost once the real vector is created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // initialize a block of memory to zero:
    alignas(std::vector<int>) char memory[sizeof(std::vector<int>)] = {};
    // use that memory as a vector, even though we haven't created any vector
    // (this is undefined behaviour! there is no vector yet!):
    std::vector<int>& vec = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(memory);
    vec.push_back(1);
    // the non-existent "phantom vector" has size 1:
    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
    // now use "placement new" to construct an empty vector in that memory:
    new (memory) std::vector<int>();
    // the real vector is empty, the element in the phantom vector is lost:
    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;    
}
```

To fix your program you need to initialize the vector before anything refers to it (specifically, before the `fooObj` constructor tries to use it, by defining it before `fooObj`).

Comment: Interesting, that's really confusing. I'm wondering if I had pushed back say 100 elements, whether that would result in a leak when it reinitialises when it gets to the vector line, or whether in fact even the one element I added leaked. I don't get what it actually does when it initialises, whether it does the equivalent of calling ::clear(). Also pushing back more than one element will reallocate, this is confusing.

Comment: It makes no difference how many objects you add to the unborn vector, they're all leaked when its constructor runs and sets the vector size to zero

Comment: Yes, I just saw by checking the address. The address of the first element of the new vector is different, meaning all of the first one is lost and unaccounted for. Weird.

Comment: @Zebrafish, There are no guarantees for what happens because you're trying to use an object that doesn't exist. The behaviour could change between compiler versions for example. Ignoring cleverness like optimization, what logically happens is `push_back` assumes the data members are valid and uses them under that assumption. Initialization would simply initialize the objects created in that memory the same as if they were unused before then. For example, write 0 to where the size member lives. Again, not guaranteed because it's undefined behaviour to use the non-existent object.

Comment: The vector constructor doesn't use `clear()`. It just sets the vector's data members to their initial values. Calling clear on an unconstructed vector would be stupid, it has nothing to clear (in a correct program, not like yours)

Comment: It's not very weird, it's quite simple to understand really. Consider creating a vector normally (without your program's bug) using the default constructor: for a typical implementation of `std::vector` all its data members will be zero or null. Now add some elements to it, so the data members are non-zero (there will be a pointer pointing to the storage for the elements). Now use `memset` to overwrite the vector's bytes with zeros: it is now identical to the original all zero state, and the pointer to the storage is leaked. This is equivalent to what your program does...

Comment: ... except that instead of using the default constructor, then overwriting the memory with zero, you start with memory that is just zeros, then add elements, then use the default constructor to write zeros to the memory again.

Answer (score 1):

if you change the code to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace List
{
    static std::vector<int> listVector;
}

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 0
        List::listVector.push_back(1);
        std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 1
    }
};
Foo fooObj;

//std::vector<int> List::listVector;

int main()
{
    std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 0
    List::listVector.push_back(2);
    std::cout << List::listVector.size() << '\n';   // Prints 1
}
```

it should work. I'm not in global variables (I don't use them) but I think the problem that the struct param don't make it real global. Maybe a other user can explain it ...

**Edit:** you can also remove the namespace, i make it so you can let the List::

**Edit2:** if you want to use with struct than it works with

```
struct List
{
    std::vector<int> listVector;
};

static List GlobL;
```

And than use GlobL.listVector, than the struct obj ist static and not the parameter of the struct.

Comment: Yes that's right, I tried writing the vector before creating the Foo object, and it didn't reset the vector (it worked properly). I think the explanation is what Jonathan Wakely said.

Comment: Zebrafish: I'm not so happy with the answer from @Jonathan Wakely, but maybe I only doesn't understand it (i cant comment there). I think the problem is the scope and your thinking of "global". In your example you make the vector only in the  scope of the List struct global. So if you use the List:: in the const function the compiler generate the vector and reuse it for every List:: entry. If you than leave the constructor, you leave the List scope and the vector is set free. To use it for your whole program you have to make it global like I did it in my example.

Comment: In my example you're right that the std::vector called listVector is in the scope of my List struct, but it never goes out of scope. You're right I shouldn't have used the word "global", because it's a static variable that's available only under the scope of the List:: struct. What I meant by global is that it's static and is initialised in the program before entering main. It never goes out of scope though, it lasts for the length of the program. So I'm pretty sure Jonathan Wakely is right.

Comment: _"I'm not so happy with the answer from @Jonathan Wakely, but maybe I only doesn't understand it "_ well my answer is correct, so I guess you don't understand it :-P Your answer provides workarounds, but doesn't explain the observed behaviour in the original buggy version of the code.

Answer (score -2):

You have to understand that your program doesn't run from top to bottom. Every programm will start at your main() function. All the code above main() will basically get ignored if it doesn't get called in the main() function.

Questions like these should not be asked here though. It seems like you are a beginner and you should start by reading yourself more into the subject before asking questions.

Comment: @chris Wow, i didnt know that. Just read about it. Neat, thanks